# dijit/form/DateTextBox not correctly parsed

Tags: javascript, date, dojo

What can be the reason of a dijit/form/DateTextBox not correctly parsed ?

Here is the scenario :

I have a page where a following control is correctly rendered :
[image: correct date]

Then the user can be redirecter to another page, and we store the date he selected on the current page. When he navigates back on the page, he should find again the date previously entered. The value of the date is correct, but it seems the Dojo control isn't correctly parsed as I'm getting the following : [image: wrong date]

In which scenario can we have a Date wrongly parsed ?

Important : I'm only getting this error on Chrome, this is working well with IE and FireFox.

Thank you very much !

Edit : the following allow to reproduce the issue :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>

    <TITLE>Dojo - RS - Date Picker demonstration</TITLE>

    <LINK rel="stylesheet" href="../dojoExtension/dojo/resources/dojo.css"                                                  

    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
        dojoConfig = {
                baseUrl: "../dojoExtension/dojo",
                parseOnLoad: false,
                async:true,
                locale: "fr-ch"
        };
    </SCRIPT>

    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="../dojoExtension/dojo/dojo.js">    </SCRIPT>

    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
        function loading() {
            require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/DateTextBox", "dojo/domReady!"], function(parser){
                parser.parse();
            });
        }

        function replaceDate() {

            require(["dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/_base/window", "dojo/parser" , "dijit/form/DateTextBox", "dojo/domReady!"], function(domConstruct,win,parser){
                var row = "<INPUT type=text data-dojo-type=dijit/form/DateTextBox name=datePickerDemo id=idDatePickerDemo >";
                try {
                    var newRow = domConstruct.place(domConstruct.toDom(row), win.body() );
                    }
                catch(err) {
                    alert(err);
                }
            });
        }

    </SCRIPT>

</HEAD>
<BODY onload="loading();"
      class="tundra">

    <DIV id="myDiv" style="position:fixed; top:150px; left:150px">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            require(["dijit/form/DateTextBox"]);
        </script>

        <INPUT type="text"
               data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" 
               name="datePickerDemo"
               id="idDatePickerDemo" />

        <a href="javascript:replaceDate()">replace the date</a>

    </DIV>


</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code setting the value into the control? And can you verify your input is a `Date`?

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. I don't have any specific code which sets the value, the control is set with the default value which is the date of the current day. Also, the control is exactly the same at the time we arrive the first time on the page and wen we navigate back on the page. Does the control first have to be destroyed ? I don't believe as it is working with IE and Firefox ...

Comment: Can you try adding `dijit/form/DateTextBox` module in the `require()` call inside `loading()`. i.e `require(["dojo/parser","dijit/form/DateTextBox", "dojo/domReady!"]`

Comment: @frank: thanks for the suggestion. I just tried but unfortunately it doesn't help.

Comment: Also, please note that in opposition to what I mentioned in my original question, the code snippet doesn't work in any browser ...

Comment: In your `replaceDate` function you're explicitly setting the value to the string `value=2017-05-05`. Since your supported date format seems to be `MM/DD/YYYY`, try setting the value in that format.

Comment: @Julien why are you re-constructing the datetime box? How do you pass the value of your stored date to the previous page? are you using local storage? You could set the existing datetime box instead with the value of your choice. e.g `datatimeWidget.set(value, new Date());` where datatimeWidget is the reference to the dojo `dijit/form/DateTextBox` widget.

Comment: @Gabriel : thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: @frank: in our application we need to re-construct it with previous user selection when navigating back on a page, and the above example reproduce the issue in a much easier way. During the navigation, the date is stored within Struts. I tried to update my example in order not to proviude any default value, but the issue still persists, seems like the parser doesn't parse the widget, and I don't get a Date picker.

Comment: @all: I updated the code example with what I have at the moment on my side.

Comment: I'm not sure the domConstruct.toDom will parse and create the DateTextBox for you. You may try and pass the newRow into the dojo.parser.parse function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `dijit/registry` to get hold of the domNode which is not correct.

`dijit/registry` will search for dojo widgets which are different from domNode objects.

`dojo/dom` module should be used for searching domNodes by id's.
i.e

```
require(["dojo/dom"], 
    function(dom){ 
      dom.byId('domId') 
    }
);
```

Have a look over [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/registry.html#dijit-registry-byid) for detailed explanation between registry.byId and dom.byId

In your instance the replaceDate() will change to

```
 function replaceDate() {

        require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/_base/window", "dojo/parser", 
                 "dijit/registry", "dijit/form/DateTextBox", "dojo/domReady!"], 
            function(dom, domConstruct,win,parser,registry){
                var row = '<INPUT type="text" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" name="datePickerDemo" id="idDatePickerDemo2" >';
                var domObject = domConstruct.toDom(row);
                try {
                    var newRow = domConstruct.place(domObject, win.body() );
                    // Use dom.byId instead of registry.byId
                    parser.parse(dom.byId("idDatePickerDemo2"));
                    }
                catch(err) {
                    alert(err);
                }
        });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, really seems to come from a "parser" issue, the following is working :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>

        <TITLE>Dojo - RS - Date Picker demonstration</TITLE>

        <LINK rel="stylesheet" href="../dojoExtension/dojo/resources/dojo.css" />
        <LINK rel="stylesheet" href="../dojoExtension/dijit/themes/dijit.css" />
        <LINK rel="stylesheet" href="../dojoExtension/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css" />
        <LINK rel="stylesheet" href="../dojoExtension/dijit/themes/tundra/form/Button.css" />
        <LINK rel="stylesheet" href="../dojoExtension/dijit/themes/tundra/form/Common.css" />

        <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
            dojoConfig = {
                    baseUrl: "../dojoExtension/dojo",
                    parseOnLoad: false,
                    async:true,
                    locale: "fr-ch"
            };
        </SCRIPT>

        <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="../dojoExtension/dojo/dojo.js"></SCRIPT>

        <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
            function loading() {
                require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/DateTextBox", "dojo/domReady!"], function(parser){
                    parser.parse();
                });
            }

            function replaceDate() {

                require(["dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/_base/window", "dojo/parser", "dijit/registry", "dijit/form/DateTextBox", "dojo/domReady!"], function(domConstruct,win,parser,registry){
                    var row = '<INPUT type="text" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" name="datePickerDemo" id="idDatePickerDemo2" >';
                    var domObject = domConstruct.toDom(row);
                    try {
                        var newRow = domConstruct.place(domObject, win.body() );
                        parser.parse(registry.byId("idDatePickerDemo2"));
                        }
                    catch(err) {
                        alert(err);
                    }
                });
            }

        </SCRIPT>

    </HEAD>
    <BODY onload="loading();"
          class="tundra">

        <DIV id="myDiv" style="position:fixed; top:150px; left:150px">

            <script type="text/javascript">
                require(["dijit/form/DateTextBox"]);
            </script>

            <INPUT type="text"
                   data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" 
                   name="datePickerDemo"
                   id="idDatePickerDemo" />

            <a href="javascript:replaceDate()">replace the date</a>

        </DIV>


    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Well, seems my problem comes more from a "parser" understanding :) ... but we can consider this specific question as resolved.

Thanks to people who answered, it definitely helped a lot !